# Как пользоваться poetry на windows, при запуске команды poetry install в папке с pyproject.toml возникает странная ошибка

Tags: python, windows, poetry

```
input was : import sys

if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
    print(sys.real_prefix)
elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
    print(sys.base_prefix)
else:
    print(sys.prefix)
```

Раньше при команде poetry install устанавливал окружение непонятно куда, но не в папку в которой нахожусь, теперь случается ошибка как показано выше. Как все это починить?

```
poetry env list

Command C:\Users\evyrf\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\auth&users-z1B85c9s-py3.10\Scripts\python.exe -W ignore - errored with the following return code 1, and o
utput:
'C:\Users\evyrf\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\auth' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
input was : import sys
if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
    print(sys.real_prefix)
elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
    print(sys.base_prefix)
else:
    print(sys.prefix)
```

Comment: Чтобы окружение создавалось в папке проекта, добавьте файл `poetry.toml` содержимым `[virtualenvs]`
`in-project = true`. По поводу ошибки - попробуйте удалить содержимое папки `C:\Users\evyrf\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache`

Comment: Есть документация: https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/ . Чтобы виртуальное окружение всегда создавалось в папке проекта, выполните команду `poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true`

Comment: @Dmitry
Не поверишь все там перечитал, такого отвратительного объяснения давно не видел

Comment: @GoodGuy, так вот же https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project

Comment: @Dmitry Я там не понял как устанавливать значение poetry config virtualenvs.in-project=true
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project = true
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project:true
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project : true
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project=:true

Comment: @GoodGuy просто закидываете файл poetry.toml такого вида в корень проекта (рядом с pyproject.toml): https://pastebin.com/zbEYN9mX . При `poetry install` окружение создастся в папке `.venv` в проекте.

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема в названии папки проекта которая содержала символ &
windows разрешает использовать в названии папок & ,а poetry и venv от этого не работают и по ошибке не понятно что из за этого.